How to change the type of 1 prop in union type in Typescript?
Lets say I have to following types:
type BaseUser = {
    id: string
    __type: "User"
}
type UserA = Omit<BaseUser, '__type'> & {
    name: string
    __type: "UserA"
}
type UserB = Omit<BaseUser, '__type'> & {
    ageB: number
    __type: "UserB"
}
type UserC = Omit<BaseUser, '__type'> & {
    name: string
    ageC: number
    __type: "UserC"
}
type User = UserA | UserB | UserC
type Request = {
    info: {
        id: string
        users: Array<User>
    }
}

The Request type takes the form of
{
    info: {
        id: string
        users: Array<{
            id: string
            name: string
            __typename: "UserA"
        } | {
            id: string
            ageB: number
            __typename: "UserB"
        } | {
            id: string
            name: string
            ageC: number
            __typename: "UserC"
        }>
}

How can I create a new type that is the same as the Request type but ageB: number / ageC: number become age: number (of course if I add a prop to lets say UserB I want the Request type to update without me updating the new type manually)? I.e.
{
    info: {
        id: string
        users: Array<{
            id: string
            name: string
            __typename: "UserA"
        } | {
            id: string
            age: number
            __typename: "UserB"
        } | {
            id: string
            name: string
            age: number
            __typename: "UserC"
        }>
}

ageB/ageC are just example names that are known and I have to specify the names it should transform. They can be for example UserB.years and UserC.grade and I should explicitly specify that I want years from UserB and grade from UserC to become age in the final type. And if a new prop gets added to a type (lets say UserB.prop4) it should exist in the Request type as is.

How do you want the utility type to decide which properties to transform? Where does the information that, for example, "ageB" becomes "age", live? If you add a new property to UserB, how does that property's name get transformed? Is there something special about the character "B" and "C" here? Are we supposed to look at the last character of the __typeName property or something? Right now this question doesn't seem to have enough details or clarity to be answered without making unwarranted guesses. Please [edit] to clarify.

@jcalz I added the requested clarification. I hope it's clearer now

You can extract A, B, C, etc from the __type prop and use to infer the cut prop names:
Playground
type MapProps<U extends object> = U extends {__type: `User${infer P}`} ?
    {[K in keyof U as K extends `${infer A}${P}` ? A : K]: U[K]}
 : never;


type Request2 = {
    info: {
        id: string,
        users: Array<MapProps<User>>
    }
}

